# What all are the various linkers connected to libraries in gcc

Tags: linker

I once tried to execute a program and it showed certain errors like `"undefined reference to sqrt"` in linux. Then I started to go through many blogs and stuffs like that and I understood that there are two processes before execution and that is compilation and linking. It would be very helpful if anyone could help me regarding various linker flags connected to their corresponding libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understood that there are two processes before execution and that is compilation and linking.

Compilation and linking are build time actions. Their result is a binary that can be immediately executed. I.e. binaries installed on your machine already went through that steps.

When a program binary is loaded, it might be necessary to dynamically load and link further libraries. This is performed by the so called dynamic linker, which is part of the operating system (some programs include their own dynamic linker though).

> I once tried to execute a program and it showed certain errors like "undefined reference to sqrt"

messages like this usually show up upon program compilation and linking, not execution. In the case of a dynamically linked program the most likely error message related to linking problems would be a message about a required library that can not be located and/or loaded.

Anyway, the `sqrt` function is part of the standard C math library `libm`. To link a library with GCC you use the `-l` flag, which takes the library name, omitting the leading `lib…` part. So in your case `-lm`

Comment: @SachinNandakumar: Well, for each library you need you have to add a `-l…`, i.e. the `-l` flag can be given multiple times. But there are much, much more flags than just `-l`. The same holds for the compiler itself. I suggest you Read The Fine Manual: [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/) and [Binutils (including linker) documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/)